# restart a specific servlet in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, restart

Can a specific Servlet on Tomcat be rebooted without stopping and starting entire Tomcat? If so how? I've tried the  approach, but that is only for debug mode (read it somewhere). So need any alternative approach.

Comment: Why do you need this? Your Tomcat servlet container creates a single instance of your Servlet class and that instance's lifecycle is bound to Tomcat's.

Comment: In order to pick up changes of a web-application on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean Web Application rather than Servlet, you can use the Tomcat Manager App to start/stop/restart individual Web Applications without restarting Tomcat. Reference: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application